# React-router-dom update 5 to 6 Object(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to upgrade react-router-dom v5 to v6.

I removed , change  to .
Now when I create simple functional component, pass to my , it works.

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
        <Route
            path="/"
            key="homepage"
            component={<MyComponent />}
        />
    </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

but when I try my real routes I get a lot of errors similar this:

```
index.tsx:66 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at Module.<anonymous> (index.tsx:66:1)
    at ./src/app/profile/component/profile-gallery-filter-form/index.tsx (index.tsx:94:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:856:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.6.57",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@js-joda/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@js-joda/timezone": "^2.12.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.2.1",
    "@repugraf/tinymce-react": "^3.8.1",
    "@sentry/react": "^6.19.2",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^6.19.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-react": "^3.13.1",
    "@types/autobahn": "^18.10.0",
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "@types/classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/emoji-mart": "^3.0.9",
    "@types/google-map-react": "^2.1.1",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.12",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.5",
    "@types/react-bootstrap-date-picker": "^4.0.9",
    "@types/react-chartjs-2": "^2.5.7",
    "@types/react-confirm": "^0.1.4",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.3",
    "@types/react-filepond": "^7.1.0",
    "@types/react-google-recaptcha": "^2.1.2",
    "@types/react-phone-number-input": "^3.0.6",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.14",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "@types/react-select": "^4.0.15",
    "@types/react-webcam": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/redux-form": "^8.3.1",
    "@types/redux-saga": "^0.10.5",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.9",
    "@use-it/event-listener": "^0.1.7",
    "@wojtekmaj/react-timerange-picker": "^3.5.0",
    "autobahn": "^20.9.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "bic-validator": "^1.27.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "connected-react-router": "^6.9.1",
    "emoji-js": "^3.6.0",
    "emoji-mart": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-deprecation": "^1.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-unicorn": "^35.0.0",
    "filepond": "^4.30.3",
    "filepond-plugin-file-validate-size": "^2.2.4",
    "filepond-plugin-file-validate-type": "^1.2.8",
    "filepond-plugin-image-preview": "^4.6.6",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fp-ts": "^2.10.5",
    "google-map-react": "^2.1.9",
    "gos-socket-client": "^0.0.4",
    "http-status-codes": "^2.1.4",
    "io-ts": "^2.2.16",
    "is-online": "^9.0.1",
    "js-file-download": "^0.4.12",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "material-ui-dropzone": "^3.5.0",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.5",
    "query-string": "^7.0.0",
    "rc-slider": "^10.0.0-alpha.5",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.3.1",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^4.0.1",
    "react-chat-widget": "git+https://github.com/krajcikondra/react-chat-widget.git#v3.1.27",
    "react-confirm": "^0.1.24",
    "react-contenteditable": "^3.3.6",
    "react-date-picker": "^8.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.3.2",
    "react-dropzone-uploader": "^2.11.0",
    "react-filepond": "^7.1.1",
    "react-flags-select": "^2.1.2",
    "react-google-recaptcha-v3": "^1.9.7",
    "react-hover-video-player": "^9.3.1",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-i18next": "^11.8.15",
    "react-image-gallery": "^1.0.9",
    "react-image-lightbox": "^5.1.4",
    "react-images-uploading": "^3.1.2",
    "react-phone-number-input": "^3.1.21",
    "react-player": "^2.9.0",
    "react-pro-sidebar": "^0.6.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-redux-i18n": "^1.9.3",
    "react-redux-toastr": "^7.6.5",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-select": "^5.2.2",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^2.0.0",
    "react-string-replace": "^1.1.0",
    "react-use-localstorage": "^3.5.3",
    "react-webcam": "^6.0.1",
    "reactjs-autobahn": "^1.8.19",
    "redux-form": "^8.3.7",
    "redux-form-dropzone": "0.0.1",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "sass": "^1.32.12",
    "simple-peer": "^9.11.0",
    "socket.io-client": "2.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
    "ts-opt": "^2.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4",
    "universal-cookie": "^4.0.4",
    "use-query-params": "^1.2.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start-dev": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts build",
    "build-dev": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --watchAll=false",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .ts,.tsx src --report-unused-disable-directives",
    "lint-fix": "eslint --ext .ts,.tsx src --report-unused-disable-directives --fix",
    "release": "bash .docker/release.sh"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.35",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.168",
    "@types/react-image-gallery": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/react-redux-i18n": "0.0.11",
    "@types/react-redux-toastr": "^7.6.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.29.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.29.3",
    "chart.js": "^3.7.1",
    "filepond-plugin-image-exif-orientation": "^1.0.11"
  }
}
```

Somebody know what is wrong? I can't figure it out. Maybe react-router-dom need other version of some other package?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you might also have an issue with some BootStrap code, can you include all relevant code you are working with? See [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

`react-router-dom@6` is completely written in typescript, so you can remove `"@types/react-router": "^5.1.14"` and `"@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3"` from the project's dependencies as they are no longer necessary and may possibly mess with any linters and transpilers your project uses.

```
npm uninstall -S @types/react-router @types/react-router-dom
```

You've also a conflicting version of `react-router` installed and it should be removed. `react-router-dom` re-exports all of `react-router` for convenience.

```
npm uninstall -S react-router
```

The only other issue I see is in the code. The `react-router-dom@6` `Route` component API changed significantly from v5; there is no longer any `component`, and `render` and `children` function props, all replaced by a single `element` prop taking a `ReactNode` value, a.k.a. JSX.

Example:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route
      path="/"
      key="homepage"
      element={<MyComponent />}
    />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately same problem after update my code and uninstall react-router library.

After 4 hours of debugging I find out problem is in import of files.

When I import file by this way:

index.tsx

```
import {profileAction} from './model';
// import {profileAction} from './model/action'; // when I change import to this it works
```

and model/index.tsx looks

```
export * from './action';
export * from './action-type';
export * from './api';
export * from './state';
export * from './sagas';
```

and model/action.ts looks:

```
export const profileAction = {...}
```

then I ever get error like this:

```
index.tsx:66 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at Module.<anonymous> (index.tsx:66:1)
    at ./src/app/profile/component/profile-gallery-filter-form/index.tsx (index.tsx:94:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:856:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
```

i haven't a clue why my imports are broken. Since update react-router-dom all imports works fine.